# Freely position Swing elements

Tags: java, swing, layout

Why are there these stupid layout managers which position my stuff. I can understand doing that on mobile platforms, where there're many different device sizes. But that's not my target. I want to freely position any component based on coordinates, like a TabbedPane, ScrollPane - where I want it.

Is there any layout-manager that let's me do what I want? Like it is common with Qt Designer, WPF, WindowsForms, and so on? Like it has to be?

Comment: Absolute positioning is evil and you should avoid it like the plague. Just change the DPI resolution of your monitor and you will understand why widgets position and size had better been handled dynamically by a `LayoutManager`. Now I can understand your frustration when faced with Swing *basic* `LayoutManager`s. But there are very good 3rd-party `LayoutManager`s out there that are worth a try.

Comment: Poor command of a skill is not a good reason to denigrate that skill set.

Comment: "Why are there these stupid layout managers which position my stuff."  There are no stupid layouts, just stupid people who won't learn to use layouts.

Comment: My background is mentioned. I also do a lot of Cocoa. Sorry for being a little more concerned about design... yeahr. Vote it down. Somebody mentions Swing Layout Managers suck. Others just use JFormDesigner or/and custom components. As mentioned. On Android I would not use fixed positions. But targeting Desktop-apps: I'm quite sure you are all wrong. And that is it. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Note that absolute positioning is NOT the norm on WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use absolute positions:

```
myPanel.setLayout(null);
JButton myButton = new JButton(myPanel);
myButton.setBounds(left, top, width, height);
```

Comment: Excuse me sir, how do I shoot my own foot?  @ffil:  "Point the fire-arm towards the ground.  Aim at chosen foot.  Squeeze (don't pull) the trigger."

Comment: That's how it works. In fact designing a GUI with these managers is impossible... if you aren't targeting command-line users ;)

Comment: @Bib I am curious to see how the UIs you design look like on small DPI monitors (72dpi), on high DPI monitors (200dpi), when the user resizes them, when the user changes the default font size at OS level. Must be terrible. Worse than command-line ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Layout managers give you great flexibly, even if you have a fixed sized frame.

I would strongly suggest using them.  Checkout the visual guide to get an idea of which ones might be useful to you.  Also, you can layer different managers to get additional effects:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: And also: take a look at 3rd-party LayoutManagers that simplify UI design and coding a lot. For a quick comparison, check out: http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/LayoutManagerShowdown

Answer (score 0):

the response is :

you should use

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Laying Out Components Using Absolute Coordinate");
```